# How to generate iframe embed code in jwplayer?

Tags: grails, iframe, jwplayer

I am using jwplayer in my grails application. I want to generate iframe embed code so that I can us it in my other website and play.How can I generate iframe embed code from jwplayer ?
Can I have exact code that needs to be generated ? Any help will be good.

Thanks
89neuron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jwplayer is working in your grails app, no reason iframe will affect its activities.

Something like

```
<iframe src="http://www.yourgrails.com"/>
```

in your reference page will suffice